# custom grouped ObservableCollection windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection which contains Title, Created Date and Result.
I need a grouped list, grouped by Created Date from the observable collection.

How to do it in C#
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you.

Grouping example:

```
<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CreatedDate"/>
    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="OtherProperty"/>
</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

Comment: is it possible to retrieve the grouped data inside the C# code instead the XAML?

Comment: got it

    var groupedData = (from data in items
                               group data by data.Created.Date into g
                               orderby g.Key
                               select new Group<string, Pushupmes>
                               {
                                   Key = g.Key.ToString(),
                                   Items = g.ToList()
                               }).ToList();

Thanks for your help :D